# Getting list/path of songs from iphone's library

Tags: objective-c, iphone

Want to create an alarm application, that will play a music file at a specific time. How can i get list of songs from iphone's library. I want to show this list in tableview, user can then select a single file that will be played at sepecified time.

Any code sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the [MPMediaPickerController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaPickerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html).

The sample code [AddMusic](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/AddMusic/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008845-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) shows how to choose (and add) music in the iPod library.